# Refresh table list after file upload in angular

Tags: angular, file-upload

There are 3 tabs in our upload application -- Home, Upload, File List. We created separate components for the 3 tabs. After uploading a file, you need to refresh the whole page to see the changes. It should automatically refresh the table list after uploading.

uploadlist.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFileList();
    };

  getFileList() {
    this.showError = false;
     this._uploadlistService.getFiles().subscribe((costSpreadsheet) => {
      console.log(costSpreadsheet);
      this.costSpreadsheet = costSpreadsheet;
      this.showLoader = false;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Error fetching file list');
        this.response = error;
        this.showLoader = false;
        this.showError = true;
      });
  }
```

upload.component.ts

```
onSubmit() {
    this.response = ('Please select a file first. ');
    this.showError = true;
    if (this.fileToUpload.name != null){
      this.showLoader = true;
      this.showSuccess = false;
      this.showError = false;
      console.log(this.fileToUpload.name);
      this.fileUploadService.fileUpload(this.fileToUpload)
        .subscribe( data => {
          console.log('Successful upload');
          this.response = 'Upload Successful';
          this.showLoader = false;
          this.showSuccess = true;    
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('Error Uploading file');
          this.response = error;
          this.showLoader = false;
          this.showError = true;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

uploadlist.service.ts

```
  getFiles(): Observable<CostSpreadsheet[]> {
    return this._http.get<CostSpreadsheet[]>(this.uploadUrl + "/spreadsheet/" + this.uploader)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<any>('getFiles')));
  }
```

I tried to copy the content of getFileList() method in upload.component.ts so it will refresh the file list after uploading. It does update the list (in the backend), but the view is still the same.

I'm getting the data from a db2 database, and we use Spring boot for backend code. I get it using the variable costSpreadsheet, and I also have a model file in angular wherein it identifies the important data I need from the backend such as the filename, total records and total amount.

Comment: Do you call somewhere `.next(...)` on your `_uploadlistService.getFiles()` Observable?

Comment: hello, please check the edit, I included the code from the service file. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `uploadlist.component.ts` the method `getFiles` is only called once, that's the cause your list does not update.

The easiest way is to notify the list to update its content.

For this you can use a Subject:

**uploadlist.service.ts**

```
public updateList$: Subject<void> = new Subject();
```

Call `.next()`on that subject in your `upload.component.ts` after the file is successfully uploaded.

And in your **uploadlist.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getFileList();

    this. _uploadlistService.updateList$.subscribe(() => {
        this.getFileList(); // Get the current files
    });
 }
```

Otherwise instead of calling `getFileListe` over and over again you can emit the uploaded file via your Subject and update your `CostSpreadsheet` array.

Comment: Great! This works :) I have another question though. It affected the delete function. At the end of each row, there's an option to delete the file. I tried to call ngOnInit() after the delete function, but it doesn't update the table. 

Here's my delete function:
`confirmDelete() {        
    this._uploadlistService.deleteFile(this.file).subscribe((data) => {
      this.costSpreadsheet = this.costSpreadsheet.filter(f => f !== this.file); }) 
  }`

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided, its very hard to see which variable is bound to the data that you are trying to display.

When you get the data back from subscribe you should do this:

```
this.someservice.subscribe((data) => {
    this.myDataToDisplay = data
})
```

You can subscribe in multiple components so all your components that represent the tabs should subscribe in this way and when the service emits new data, all the components should update. You should subscribe inside the ngOnInit method of each component.

If the components are not in existence such that they are not listening when the service emits new data then you may want to consider using an RxJS behaviour subject inside your service or use a global store solution such as ngrx store.